# How can I get my crew to stop cheering?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

My crew has been cheering for 4 hours non stop and I don't know how to fix it. It all started when I was doing the siege of Charles-Towne. How can I get them to stop?

Comment: "Stop having fun!"

Comment: Yell something pirate-y at them like "The next one of you rum-soaked deck-hounds that makes so much as a peep will be fishing a shot from his liver!" and then, to show solidarity, shoot the man in the Crow's Nest when he spots land.

Comment: lol, show us some image.

Answer (score 1):

Do the next mission and it should stop